# C# Error Finding Item in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I'm trying to search a ListView to see if a certain piece of text has already been added. I've tried using other answers from here, like the code below:

```
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText(txtSearch.Text);
if (item != null)
{
   // you have match
}
```

However, it highlights a problem with "FindItemWithText". The error message is:

'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'FindItemWithText' and no extension method 'FindItemWithText' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using some LINQ

```
if(listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(c => c.Content.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)))
{
    // You have a match
}
```

Comment: I tried using this but i'm getting a similar error, except now its to do with .Text: Error 1 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Any ideas??

Comment: try replacing 'Text' with 'Content.ToString()'

Comment: Thanks, that sorted that issue. I apologise, I'm new to this, so just one more stupid question... Where does that fit in with the original code? So if the item is already in the ListView, do something; otherwise, do something else?

Comment: I've changed the .Where() to .Any() and put it into an if statement for you.

Comment: Looks like its returning custom objects. You could cast to Symptoms and then access the relevant property within the Any statement. It's a bit hard to update the example without knowing a bit more about Symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can implement an extension method which will do what you want.
Consider a stupid example:

```
public static class ListViewExtensions {
    public static object FintItemWithText(this ListView lv, string text) {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items) {
            if (item.Content.ToString() == text) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it like in the following example:

```
object result = listView.FintItemWithText("A");
```

I just here work with objects. It's not a good practice usually. Maybe it would be better to roll out your own class, create a list (or ObservableCollection) of it and set a binding. Than, when you know the type of items inside your ListView you can easily cast to the well known type and check it's properties as you like.

Comment: I get a different problem when I try to use this :( It says the extension method has to be in a non-generic static class. Not exactly sure what that means. Do you know how I could resolve this?

Comment: What have you done, you've copy-pasted my code? Make sure that my code is declared out of any classes. Make it top-level inside the namespace, but not inside any classes.